# Iterating through a folder and converting all text files to csv files Error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text, file-conversion

I ran a Powershell code that outputted a bunch of text files.

The text files look like this:

This is my `aText.txt`

```
    Clark Kent
    Dolly Parten
    Charlie Brown
    Gary Numan
```

It's just text files with names, no header. I want these to now be converted to csv files, so I turned to Python and wrote this code:

```
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    
    folder = '\path\text\'
    csvFolder = '\path\csv\'
    
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
            csvpath = os.path.join(csvFolder, filename)
            
            #if file is empty
            if os.stat(file_path).st_size == 0:
                df = pd.DataFrame()
    
            #for other files
            else:
                df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=0, names=None)
    
            csv_path = os.path.splitext(csvpath)[0] + '.csv'
    
            df.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)
    
    
    print("Text files have been converted to csv")
```

When I ran it, it gave me an error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

I did some research but didn't see anything for Pandas, only for the csv function. Someone included this under some responses:

```
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding='cp1252', header=0, names=None)
```

I tried it out and the program ran, but the csv files were corrupted with strange characters.
I tried this on a test folder where I created text files and it ran fine and the output was good, but with the text files created from Powershell, the code runs (**with no error messages**) but the output isn't correct.

Here is an example of what I am seeing in the csv files after the conversion:

```
    ¿ Ã Ÿâ
```

The `else statement` seems to be where the error is occurring since this is where the conversion takes place. I ran `df`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding='cp1252', header=0, names=None)
print("This is df: ", df)
```

This is the sample output:

```
This is df:      ÿþA
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: John, I updated my question. But I realized now how to fix the issue. I had the encoding completely wrong, since they're not encoded in the default UTF-8 that Pandas auto-assumes.

Comment: @noobCoder, can I answer my own question? You betcha! https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: "use the right encoding when opening the file" isn't a very interesting solution.  If that's all it was, you're probably better off just deleting the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I blew this issue out of proportion. I thought this was a much larger issue, but just playing around with the encoding while I waited for a response seemed to fix this. I simply added `utf-16` in the encoding:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding='utf-16', header=0)
print("this is df: \n", df)
```

The output:

```
this is df:
Clark Kent
Dolly Parten
Charlie Brown
Gary Numan
```